# Symmetric Group acting on $X \times X$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions

The symmetric group $S_n$ acts on the set $X = \{1,\ldots,n\}$ and hence acts on $X \times X$ by $g(x,y) = (gx, gy)$. Determine the orbits of $S_n$ on $X \times X$.

Not sure how do I actually "determine" the orbits? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Not really sure what the question is... Why don't you look at $n=3$, find the orbits by hand, and then generalize?

Comment: it should be "Determine the orbits on $X\times X$ by the action of $S_n$".

Comment: @janmarqz I just followed the wording of the question, hence it can be quite confusing.

Comment: agree, i didn't mean to answer you, i was thinking that OP is looking his own post

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try breaking $X \times X$ into $A:=\{(x,y) \in X \times X:x=y \}$ and $B=\{(x,y) \in X \times X:x \neq y \}$.

Comment: So does that mean that for A, my orbit is {(a,a): a$\in$ X} and for B, my orbit is {(b,c): b,c $\in$ X, b $\neq$ c}?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are the orbits, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yeah, is that correct?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$